# c# beginner using stream reader to read in a txt file

Tags: streamreader

i'm having trouble reading in a text file which contains 9 sets of three integer values separated by commas. This is what i have done so far, but how would i be able to read through the data going down row one to get a max value?
very stuck with a program the data text file looks like

- 21,7,11
- 20,10,12
- 17,7,18

these represent temperature, height and carbon%
i have read in the file as so

```
 {
        string s;
        System.IO.StreamReader inputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(DataFile);
        s = inputFile.ReadLine();
        int noDataLines = int.Parse(s);

        double[,] data = new double[noDataLines, 3];
        string[] ss;

   is this right if the data is stored in the debug folder as a .txt file?
```

from here how would i go about getting a max temp(ie only reading the first vertical column of data)?

Comment: The first line contains the number of lines?

Comment: well its a 9 x 3 grid, however when tested you should be able to change the value of 9 but not 3 as they represent fixed variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply use mixture of System.IO `File.ReadLines()` method and LINQ  `.ToList()` in order to read all text lines to `List<string>`. At this point we can just iterate through the collection parsing double values from text lines :

```
        List<string> lines = File.ReadLines("filepath").ToList();

        List<int[]> values = new List<int[]>();
        int[] temp = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] strValues = lines[i].Split(',');

            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < strValues.Length; i2++)
                temp[i2] = Convert.ToInt32(strValues[i2]);

            values.Add(temp.ToArray());
        }
```

Or we can use LINQ :

```
        List<string> lines = File.ReadLines("filepath").ToList();

        List<int[]> values = new List<int[]>();
        int[] temp = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            values.Add(lines[i].Split(',')
                .Select(l => Convert.ToInt32(l)).ToArray());
```

Comment: ow would i find max temp?